# How to sort file sizes that are in human readable format?

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qt5

How to sort the following numbers that are in the column of `QTableView`? I use `QSortFilterProxyModel` for sorting.

```
123 B
1 KB
131 KB
3 GB
322 GB
337 KB
3 MB
555 KB
52 TB
```

Comment: you'll just need a function that takes the human readable format and outputs a number

Comment: Probably the model should also contain a raw size in bytes, then you sort on that. There's no point having to convert _back_ if you don't need to, and that seems easy to defeat by localisation and suchlike anyway.

Comment: You convert it back to human unreadable format and compare. Or you keep that format separately.

Comment: Good point. The "for humans" text should never be stored, but rather computed when it is actually displayed for humans. @underscore_d

Comment: In any case, I think for SO, this needs specific code showing what is done, so a solution can be suggested. It seems too vague right now.

Comment: @KennyOstrom true, otherwise you'll get a nightmare trying to interpret _translated_ human-readable sizes...

Comment: So, I have to create a custom model, there is no other way?

Comment: Add a separate role to your source model, returning the unformatted raw size. Then use that as sort role with the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Basically subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel` and implement [`lessThan`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan).

Also, it would be better if you use a separate model's role to store the actual size in bytes instead of converting the displayed value. In this case, the comparison method would be something like

```
class MySortFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
public:
  MySortFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
  bool lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const override {
    const auto left_bytes = left.data(SIZE_IN_BYTES_ROLE).toULongLong();
    const auto right_bytes = right.data(SIZE_IN_BYTES_ROLE).toULongLong();

    return left_bytes < right_bytes;
  }
};
```

If, for any reason, you still use the display role, you should get the text from the indices and convert the string to bytes before comparing. For the conversion function, you have several options, like splitting the string into the number and the unit, and then using a look-up table to get the multiplier factor of the unit.

```
class MySortFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
public:
  MySortFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
  bool lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const override {
    const auto left_bytes = toBytes(left.data().toString());
    const auto right_bytes = toBytes(right.data().toString());

    return left_bytes < right_bytes;
  }

private:
  static int64_t toBytes(const QString& size)
  {
    static const QMap<QString, int64_t> s_sizes = {
      {"b", 1},
      {"kb", 1024},
      {"mb", 1024 * 1024},
      {"gb", 1024 * 1024 * 1204},
      {"tb", 1024 * 1024 * 1204 * 1024},
    };

    const auto tokens = size.toLower().split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
    if (tokens.size() == 0) return 0; // error
    const auto number = tokens[0].toInt();
    if (tokens.size() == 1) return number; // assume bytes
    return number * s_sizes.value(tokens[1], 0); // 0 for unknown units
  }
};
```

You can check a more complete example of how to subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel` [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-customsortfiltermodel-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

When I have to define my comparison I write some model inherited from QSortFilterProxyModel and override virtual function QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan.